# How to create a Cloudant Query with arithmetic operations

Tags: sql, nosql, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I need to collect documents inside this Cloudant database I have where the sum of two properties equals something else.

In SQL, I would perform some like this

```
select * from table where property1 + property2 > 20;
```

And it would sucessfully bring all results that match this operation.

How do I perform a similar search comparing the value of two properties in a Cloudant query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think [mango-style queries](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/api/database/find.html#selector-syntax) provide the functionality to do such arithmetic expressions. I suggest taking a look at regular [views](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/ddocs/ddocs.html#view-functions). You might even want to use [show functions](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/ddocs/ddocs.html#list-functions) for updating the constant interactively.

Comment: I created a view with the operation I needed and it solved my problem. Thanks.